# How to prevent udev from adding fd0 to /proc/partitions?

Tags: linux, udev, block-device, floppy

I'm updating `udev` to `eudev`, the issue I am having is now `fd0` shows in `/proc/partitions` which causes hang delays by things that process items from that file.

I would imagine it's some "rule" but I have no clue what the rules actually do.  For instance, udisks2 rules sets some environment variable ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY to 1 via `KERNEL==”fd*”, ENV{ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY}=”1″` but what they heck does that do?  I look for anything using an environment variable named `ID_DRIVE_FLOPPY` and find nothing, even in the udev source.   If I set that to "0", fd0 still shows up in `/proc/partitions`.

Any idea on what to do?  I still would like `/dev/fd0` to work if manually mounted, but don't want it showing in `/proc/partitions` (used by `fdisk -l`, `mdadm xxx --scan`, and others).  That's how the old `udev 175` I was using was doing it, now using `udev 228`.

Comment: Are you comparing udev 175 and 228 on the same kernel? Could you clarify what eudev has to do with your question?

Comment: same kernel.   Just different udev.  /proc/partitions is only populated after the `udevadm trigger` call.   Just that the version used is eudev, doesn't rely on systemd.

Comment: Which [release of `eudev`](https://github.com/gentoo/eudev/releases) are you using? 228 is a `udev` release, not `eudev`.

Comment: It's 3.2.8 but it still prints out 228.